# Stupid question but unsure on Regression.

Tags: regression, percentages, linear-regression

When I want to do a regression between daily change of currency prices and a daily stock index changes which one shall I use as the dependent and independent variable. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If $y=mx+b$ then $x=\frac{1}{m}y-\frac{1}{m}b$.

Comment: Not sure you can re-arrange the regression line this way though. If $x =m_1 y+ b_1$  I doubt that the best estimate of $m_1$ is $\frac{1}{m}$. It still does not matter which variable is which, but you have to work out the regression line in each case separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't ultimately matter but I would imagine that daily stock index is the dependent variable and daily change of currency prices is the independent variable

Comment: Thanks for the input, good to know you see it like that.